# Filefield with IMCE browse server

Tags: media, files

I am having rather strange issue. I have created custom CCK with image upload field. To browse a server folders I've installed a CCK Filefield and configured it to work with IMCE , however I can't see images (uploaded with FTP), unless I upload them through IMCE itself. The strange thing is that in Description field I have also IMCE file browser wich "see" correctly all images. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: What users are owners of files uploaded via FTP? And who's owner of those uploaded with IMCE?

Comment: "Administrator" is the owner of those uploaded with IMCE. I've read about this isue in some posts but, if this is the case than why I see them correctly in IMCE file browser which is located in Description field ?

Comment: one owner does not help, as we can't compare it to anything. The point is to find a difference between these 2 kind of files. Only then we can try to find out why that difference matters. Tell us how these files are different. My guess was file system owner recorded for them, but it may be something else.

Comment: I cant find the owner of the file in CPANEL it just show the user which is the same for all files

Comment: Have I told you I don't love cPanel? Guess not. Sorry, I can't help you if I don't know what's the difference between files, and it's probably in uid, gid or mode. Don't think cPanel is going to tell you them.

Comment: I've cheked file owners via FileZilla and it seems they are the same for all files (Owner:10059 Group:505)

Comment: So my usual solutions just went down the drain. At least you avoided most common configuration errors.

Comment: As I said this is a very strange while it works in CKEditor and not in Filefield

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the above problem, I have installed the [IMCE for FileField](https://drupal.org/project/imce_filefield) module; everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reference the files directory as "." NOT as "sites/default/files" in your IMCE profile settings. (Per the Directory instructions below: "To specify file system root, just enter .(dot) character.")